# ActiveAdmin custom alert message on destroy

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activeadmin

Had noticed the following in the documentation:

```
batch_action :destroy, confirm: "Are you sure??" do |ids|
  # ...
end
```

Any thoughts as to what I may not have accounted for in terms of setting a custom alert message on destroy?

Comment: can you provide some details? what are you tying to achieve? what is failing? batch action or plain action?

Comment: did you get it working?